# Grid does not remember elements added dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, invalidoperationexception

I am attempting to populate a grid in my MainPage with web browser items which are added in the code behind. For some reason, I cannot get the grid to remember which elements have been added already. I am unsure of how to store this information so that when the MainPage is navigated from, and then back to, the grid knows which values were previously added. To better explain, what I have is as follows:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="BrowserHost" Grid.Row="1">
    //Items will be added in code behind
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void ShowTab(int index) 
    {
        this.currentIndex = index;
        int count = Settings.BrowserList.Value.Count;

        if (count <= 0)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show("count <= 0");
        }
        if (currentIndex <= (count - 1))  //in correct range
        {
            // BrowserHost does not remember previously added children elements added previously when navigated back to this page and performing this check
            if(!BrowserHost.Children.Contains(Settings.BrowserList.Value[currentIndex].Browser))
                //Attempt to add browser if it was already added previously throws InvalidOperationException
                BrowserHost.Children.Add(Settings.BrowserList.Value[currentIndex].Browser);
        }

        if (currentIndex > (count - 1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("currentIndex > (count - 1)");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Settings.BrowserList.Value.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Settings.BrowserList.Value.ElementAt(i) != null)
            {
                Settings.BrowserList.Value.ElementAt(i).Browser.Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially, the `ShowTab` method is called with a specific index value everytime the MainPage loads. A check is performed to see if `Settings.BrowserList.Value[currentIndex].Browser` (a collection with web browser instances) exists at the currentIndex in the list (these are added in another page). If the `BrowserHost` grid on MainPage already contains the child element (a browser) with a particular index, then it should skip over the check and continue to show that browser instance on the screen. This is supposed to basically implement a tabbed browsing scenario for a custom web browser control I have created. My issue is, I can consecutively add new browsers to `BrowserHost` and show them on the screen, but when I try to call a previously added webbrowser at  certain index in my collection, I get an InvalidOperationException. How would I fix this? My debugging shows that in `ShowTab` when I check to see if a browser has been added, regardless of it has or not, it jumps into attempting to add that browser to `BrowserHost` child element. If the browser has been created previously, thats when the InvalidOperationException occurs.

Comment: I did a quick test with a more naïve case, and there seems to be nothing faulty with the way Grid is implemented - it worked as expected. Contains() returned the expected value. Before your if(Contains) line, add the following and tell us what the result is (stop in debug and inspect `exists`): `var exists = BrowserHost.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x == Settings.BrowserList.Value[currentIndex].Browser);`

Comment: `exists` is null before an item is added to BrowserHost, and also null after an item is added to BrowserHost. It is also null when I leave MainPage and then return and try to show that same BrowserList index item. I am adding new items to `BrowserList` in another page though. I believe that leaving MainPage is causing the Grid to not remember the items that have been added. Having the grid remember the items is necessary though because if my user exits the app and then returns, it must be able to call the previously added browser items.

Comment: Ooooooh. So these elements may be parented by different pages?

Comment: Well, I'm essentially trying to create tabs on one page, and when a user clicks a tab, it shows the corresponding BrowserList item on the MainPage. The thing is, the TabsPage has a listbox that is populated by the BrowserList items as well, so the user can tap the item of choice and show that corresponding item on the MainPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you are doing is a good idea. However, the issue seems to be that the control is already parented by a different control and so you cannot add it again. Try doing the following:

```
var browser = Settings.BrowserList.Value[currentIndex].Browser;
if(!BrowserHost.Children.Contains(browser))
{

  var grid = (Grid)browser.Parent;
  if (grid != null)
  {
    grid.Children.Remove(browser);
  }
  BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser);
}
```

You also need to make sure that the Browser is placed in a Grid in your other form (if it's not directly inside a Grid, just wrap it in one).

This may work, but I **strongly** suggest you find a different way of doing it.

Comment: That did work for showing an existing browser instance on the screen, although all history data and whatnot is removed. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer though because it is a working solution, and I really do appreciate the help. I will try to post back if I find another solution.